# Remove title and category description from category pages except first

Tags: magento2, category, catalog, seo

i need to remove (not displaying:none or similar) title and category description from category catalog pages different from first page.

I mean, when i click on pages on pagination selector, i want category and title description only on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Magento_Catalog > layout>catalog_category_view.xml
and add this code.

```
<referenceBlock name="category.description" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: not what i asked. category description has to be visible on the first category page, pages 2,3,4,5 etc don't have to show h1 and description